# How can we add a UIGestureRecognizer to Outlet Collection?

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer, iboutletcollection

I'm trying to add a tap gesture to an outlet collection of labels [UILabel], like this:

```
@IBOutlet var subLabels: [UILabel]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(HomePageViewController.selectSubLabel(tap:)))
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

            for i in (0..<(subLabels.count)) {
                subLabels[i].addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            }
    }

    func selectSubLabel(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            print("Gesture Is WORKING!")
        }
```

and i tried to add it on a single label in storyboard; but NONE are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the `User Interaction Enabled` Attribute of your `UIlabel`'s in `Attribute inspector` of Xcode. `User Interaction Enabled` must be ticked for detecting the tap. Please see the picture below,

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need to allow user interaction on a label (it is turned off by default):

```
for i in (0..<(subLabels.count)) {
    subLabels[i].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    subLabels[i].addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

but gesture recognizer can observe for gestures only in one view. 
So, there are two options:

I. Dedicated gesture recognizer for every label

```
for i in (0..<(labels.count)) {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectSubLabel(tap:)))
    labels[i].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    labels[i].addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

II. One gesture recognizer for the parent view of the labels

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in (0..<(labels.count)) {
        subLabels[i].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectSubLabel(tap:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func selectSubLabel(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = tap.location(in: view)
    guard let label = subLabels.first(where: { $0.frame.contains(touchPoint) }) else { return }

    // Do your stuff with the label
}
```